# How to create a typescript decorator with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a react class decorator that adds a few props to any react component and returns the decorated component with it's current props plus the additional props from the decorator.

I was able to find working code for a regular typescript class decorator which can found on typescript's [decorator handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html). However, this is for a generic class. It doesn't include any react types.

Below is something similar that I'd like to accomplish with React and Typescript:

```js
@AddOtherProps
class BasicComponent extends React.Component {

  static defaultProps = {
    someProp: ''
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SomeComponent 
        someProp={this.props.someProp} // This is from current component
        otherProp={this.props.propFromDecorator} // This is from the decorator
      >
        {'Component Content'}
      </SomeComponent>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic decorator would function like an HoC wrapper

```
function decorate(DecoratedComponent) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <DecoratedComponent {...this.props} injectedProp="Hello" />;
    }
  };
}
```

you would use it like

```
@decorate
class App extends React.Component { ... }
```

[Here's a working example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/k24zrx218v)

Comment: I get an error when trying this out:
`TS1238: Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.
  Type 'typeof (Anonymous class)' is not assignable to type 'typeof ExampleComponent'.
    Property 'defaultProps' is missing in type 'typeof (Anonymous class)'.`

Comment: Types in the example throw ts-error: ``Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.
  Type 'ComponentClass<{ injectedProp: string; nonInjectedProp: string; }>' is not assignable to type 'typeof App'.
    Construct signature return types 'Component<{ injectedProp: string; nonInjectedProp: string; }, ComponentState>' and 'App' are incompatible.
      The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
        Type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'Element'.
          Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type Element.ts(1238)``